# Docker Compose Detach Mode Parameter Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my docker-compose file, mysql.yml:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql 
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: db
    restart: always 
    networks:
      - db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example1
    command: bash -c "apt update"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    container_name: web
    networks:
      - db 
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  db:
    external: true
```

When I run this file as "docker-compose -f mysql.yml up -d" it starts working, but after 5 or 10 seconds it dies with 0 exit code. Then, it restarts due to "restart: always" parameter.

I search on the internet about my problem and got some solutions:

First one,

```
tty: true
std_in_open: true
```

parameters, but they are not working. The container dies anyway.

Second one,

```
entrypoint:
  - bash
  - -c
command:
  - |
    tail -f /dev/null
```

This solution is working, but it overrides the default entrypoint, and, so my MySQL service does not work at the end.

Yes, I can concatenate entrypoints or create a Dockerfile(I actually want to complete all this in a single file), but I think it' s not the right way and I need some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you change it to not restart immediately, are you able to see any errors logged?

Comment: No, there are no errors except "exited code(0)". Also, after, removing restart parameters it remains as dead.

Comment: Idk. Some thoughts: I wonder if removing the bash and calling `command: ["apt", "update"]` would show an error. Also, you have 2 commands listed, That may be ok, for all I know... Also, I think if you aren't running as root, you will have trouble running `apt update`, i would surmise...

Comment: I don't know what best practice for `apt update`-ing containers is. I usually see that done in a docker file before it gets to docker compose. I would guess you would run into a problem doing it here in a compose file because you won't be running as root in docker-compose, so you won't have access to run `apt update`.  I may be wrong though.

Comment: So, depending on your use case, I guess you could either 1) create a docker file to build and update the image, then reference that image in the compose file or 2) for now don't worry about updating the image and use the entrypoint/comment to start your mysql server or whatever.

Comment: "apt update" command works fine. After, completing all it' s tasks, it restarts.

Comment: I guess that shows how much I know. So, the issue is you want to add a command after that? Can you do `command: ["apt", "update", "&&", "echo", "blah"]`?

Comment: When I try `command: ["apt", "update", "&&", "echo", "blah"]` it gives "E: The update command takes no arguments". The funny is this,  I split them as `command: ["apt", "update"] \command: ["echo", "blah"]`, it only runs the last one. The output was "bla \bla \ bla". Then, I add one more `command: ["echo", "blah1"]` and get the output as bla1 \bla1 \ bla1". :S:S:S

Comment: Can you call a script that does both?

Comment: Can you give specific details about it please?

Comment: I just mean call something like `command: ["/path/to/script.sh"]` and in that script run `apt update` and whatever else you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Compose setup says:

```yaml
command: bash -c "apt update"
```

This is the *only* thing the container does; this runs *instead of* the normal container process.  Once that command completes (successfully) the container will exit (with status code 0).

In normal operation you shouldn't need to specify the `command:` for a container; the Dockerfile will have a `CMD` line that provides a useful default.  (The notable exception is a setup where you have both a Web server and a background worker sharing substantial code, so you can set `CMD` to run, say, the Flask application but override `command:` to run a Celery worker.)

Many of the other options you include in the `docker-compose.yml` file are unnecessary.  You can safely remove `tty:`, `stdin_open:`, `container_name:`, and `networks:` with no ill effects.  (You can [configure the Compose-provided `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) if you specifically need containers running on a pre-created network.)

---

The comments hint at trying to run package updates at container startup time.  I'd echo @xdhmoore's comment here: you should only run APT or similar package managers during an image build, never on a running container.  (You don't want your application startup to fail because a Debian mirror is down, or because an incompatible update has gotten deployed.)

For the standard Docker Hub images, in general they update somewhat frequently, especially if you're not pinning to a specific patch release.  If you run

```sh
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

it will ask Docker Hub for a newer version of the image, and recreate the container on it if needed.

The standard Docker Hub packages also frequently download and install the thing they're packaging outside their distribution's package manager system, so running an upgrade isn't necessarily useful.

If you must, though, the best way to do this is to write a minimal Dockerfile

```sh
FROM mysql
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get upgrade --assume-yes
```

and reference it in the `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
services:
  db:
    build: .
    # replacing the image: line
    # do NOT leave `image: mysql` behind
```